Is there a general connection between non-analytic features of scattering amplitudes and intermediate particles going on-shell?
For example, in the polology section of Schwartz book it is shown that whenever a product of fields has a non-trivial overlap with an intermediate one-particle state, greens functions involving said product will have a pole at the mass of said state. It is also known that the two particle scattering amplitude has a cut starting at $s=(2m)^2$ arising because of the diagrams in which intermediate two particle states go on-shell. Can one show that for diagrams on which two particle states cannot go on-shell the resulting amplitude will be analytic in $(2m)^2\leq s\leq (3m)^2$? I think I just need a better understanding of the non-analytic behaviour of amplitudes and their connection to on-shell intermediate particles.

There are examples of anomalous thresholds which show that the connection can be quite subtle.
